# EntityFramework.Migrations, using DbMigrator in a C# class

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, migration

I just installed the new EntityFramework.Migrations package. I scaffoled my migrations following this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-no-magic-walkthrough.aspx

Using the Powershell window, everything works fine.

But we need to create a class that will rollback all the migrations for our automated tests.

So I made a simple class that looks like this:

```
public class CustomMigrator
{
    public void DropDatabase()
    {
        new DbMigrator(new Settings()).Update("0");
    }

    public void RegenerateDatabase()
    {
        new DbMigrator(new Settings()).Update();
    }
}
```

Settings is my DbMigrationContext implementation that looks like this:

```
public class Settings : DbMigrationContext<MyDb>
{
    public Settings()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetCodeGenerator<CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator>();
        AddSqlGenerator<SqlConnection, SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator>();
    }
}
```

When I call this:

```
new CustomMigrator().DropDatabase();
```

I get a weird exception:

```
The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

I know that Migrations are still in alpha, but I was wondering if anyone have been able to run the migrations using DbMigrator?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me. I did create my scaffolds from a Code-First context. Are you working with an existing schema?

Comment: I am using code first also, and nope not working from an existing schema, I created my database using my first scaffolds that generates my whole database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my problem, it is because I was using EntityFrameworkProfiler and there is a bug with the latest EF release that breaks the profiler.

http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/5121/entity-framework-june-2011-ctp-v4-2-is-now-supported-in-entity-framework-profiler

For the moment I did not need the profiler, so I just removed the line of code that was initializing the profiler and now it works.